# Image Preprocessing for better results with tesseract on reciepts

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to use Tesseract for text extraction on receipts. Some results are good when not doing any preprosessing but there are some reciepts that are really bad and can't extract much of the text. The quality of the reciepts are in general good without skrewness, shadow and so on (you can see the text clearly).

I have been trying to do some preprocessing to improve the text extraction. I have both tried Tesseracts own suggestions (https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality) and some posts on stackoverflow but just getting worse result.

I've been trying to use openCV for the preprosessing. Here are some of the functions I've tried which gave a bad result.

```
Cv2.MedianBlur(img,img,3); //for noise removal
Cv2.Filter2D(img,img,img.Depth(),test); //for noise removal
Cv2.CvtColor(img,img,ColorConversionCodes.RGB2GRAY); //for grayscale
Cv2.Threshold(img,img,150,255,ThresholdTypes.Binary); //for Binarize
Cv2.Resize(img,img,new OpenCvSharp.Size(300,300)); //for DPI
```

Here is a reciept before preprocessing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUTAj.jpg 
and here is same reciept after the preprocessing stage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwcqF.jpg.

If you look at the second picture I get why I'm getting bad results. Can anyone help me improve the preprocessing or give me some tips?